# How to make admin account

Tags: pi-2

I'm having my permission denied when I'm trying to download or view some files. I've attempted to run the following commands:

```
sudo adduser admin
```

and

```
sudo adduser admin sudo
```

but neither work.

Comment: You should be able to do all of this as the Pi user, why are you adding a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an account and add that account to the sudoers group which grants complete administrative access to that account by running the following command:

```
sudo adduser mohammad sudo
```

Don't forget to Change "Mohammad" with the actual name of the account you wish to create, after pressing enter you will be prompted to create a password for that account, if you do not enter a password but skip that step that account will not have a password.

Comment: I have problem with VNC access denied after install...not sure Apache, PHP, MariaDB some of these. However, after use this command to add **pi** user to **sudo** group and everything back to work fine again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this unless you're certain that you want and need a true root account. sudo will take care of root tasks for you nicely in almost all cases.

However, if you do want a root account so you can log in as root or su to a root account, just type:

```
sudo passwd
```

This will let you enter a password for the root account. Be careful to make it a secure one!

One other modification you should do, if you enable a root account, is to forbid root logins via ssh for security reasons. You can log in using a normal user account instead (such as pi), and use the su command to become root. To do this:

```
cd /etc/ssh
sudo nano sshd_config
```

(You can do this as root too of course; just don't type sudo in front of the command.) Find the line:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Change yes to no. (If yours already says no then there is nothing to do.) Save the config file, and to make it take effect:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

to log in then use `su -` and type in the UNIX password.